# Trim field in linq2sql query without breaking index

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am joining on the zip codes from 2 different tables that have a tons of data and are indexed on zip code.
 The join works if I trim off the digits on t.zipplus4 so both zip code fields are only 5 digits.
 Unfortunately using substring or replace break the indexing so the query takes too long.
 I obviously cant use trimstart? bc it doesnt exist in sql. 
In sql left([Zip Code], 5) works just fine with the index. 
Is there any way in linq I can pull this off?

example:

```
  var query = (from t in db.test
             join g in db.test2 on t.zipplus4 equals g.zip
             select t).ToList();
```

Comment: You could alternatively add a computed column to your table (which is suitably trimmed) and index that.  Then your Linq query will be efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible to do the trim in linq without breaking the index. The answer was to ditch linq2sql for ado.net so you get all sql functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent for `LEFT` in c# is a [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which translates into tsql's `SUBSTRING` function which is not a choice for you.

If you just want to trim unnecessary spaces, use [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method, it will be converted into something like `LTRIM(RTRIM([t0].[zipplus4]))`.

You may try to use tsql's `LIKE` (it's not clear from the question if `LIKE` is suitable here) by using [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx):

```
var query = (from t in db.test
             from g in db.test2
             where SqlMethods.Like(t.zipplus4, g.zip + '%')
             select t).ToList();
```

But I'm not sure if this breaks the indexes.

If all this is not an option for you, consider creating [a stored procedure](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) for this.

Comment: I ditched linq for straight ado. A stored procedure would have worked but isnt what I wanted.